# How to filter an Array with Checkboxes items?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to filter my checkboxes I search it on internet there was information but I couldn't work it with my code.

**This is the webpage**
[image]

I want when you click on the checkbox it must be same as the category.

This is some code of the checkbox:

```
<div>
  <input class="form-check-input checkboxMargin" type="checkbox" value="All" v-model="selectedCategory">
  <p class="form-check-label checkboxMargin">All</p>
</div>
```

This is my grey box layout:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
        <div class="card rounded-circle mt-5" v-for="item of items" :key="item['.key']">
          <div>
            <div class="card-body defaultGrey">
              <h5 class="card-title font-weight-bold">{{ item.name }}</h5>
              <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-sm ">
                  <div class="row ml-0"><h6 class="font-weight-bold">Job:</h6><h6 class="ml-1">{{ item.job }}</h6></div>
                  <div class="row ml-0"><h6 class="font-weight-bold">Category:</h6><h6 class="ml-1">{{ item.categories }}</h6></div>
                  <div class="row ml-0"><h6 class="font-weight-bold">Location:</h6><h6 class="ml-1">{{ item.location }}</h6></div>
                  <div class="row ml-0"><h6 class="font-weight-bold">Niveau:</h6><h6 class="ml-1">{{ item.niveau }}</h6></div>
                  <div class="row ml-0"><h6 class="font-weight-bold">Availability:</h6><h6 class="ml-1">{{ item.availability }}</h6></div>
                  <h6>{{ item.info }}</h6>
                  <div class="row ml-0"><h6 class="font-weight-bold">Posted:</h6><h6 class="ml-1">{{ item.user }}</h6></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-1 ml-3" v-if="isLoggedIn">
                  <router-link :to="{ name: 'InternshipDetails', params: {id: item['.key']} }" class="btn bg-info editbtn">
                    Details
                  </router-link>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-1 ml-3 mr-3" v-if="isLoggedIn && item.user == currentUser">
                  <router-link :to="{ name: 'Edit', params: {id: item['.key']} }" class="btn btn-warning editbtn">
                    Edit
                  </router-link>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-1" v-if="isLoggedIn && item.user == currentUser">
                  <button @click="deleteItem(item['.key'])" class="btn btn-danger dltbtn">Delete</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And I have my object here but how can I filter my grey boxes with category:

```
selectedCategory: []
```

Comment: I'd know if your cards are all visible by default.

Comment: They are all visible. But I want to filter it with the checkboxes.

Comment: Filter your original Array `items` and assign it to `selectedCategory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use computed properties:

```
computed: {
   filteredItems(){
      if(this.selectedCategory.length == 0) return this.items;
      return this.items.filter(el => {
         for(let i = 0; i < this.selectedCategory.length; i++){
            if(el.categories == this.selectedCategory[i]) return el;
         }
      });

   }
}
```

Then you go for `v-for="item of filteredItems"`

I didnt tested it. If you provide me more code i could help you more

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `one-way` binding between your `CategoryCheckBox` component and your `ListCard` component.

Because you provided separated code when I can not reproduce it to give you a solution based on your own, I suggest this example to explain my solution.

**Step One:**

You have many ways to CRUD your `items` using a [Plugins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) or [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) or [global instance](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#Base-Example), in my example I used global instance in `main.js`

```
Vue.prototype.$myArray = ["Books", "Magazines", "Newspaper"];
```

I assume you created your `items` data in the `ListCards` component

**Step Two:**

You need to add `@change` event in your `checkbox` to handle `checked` and `unchecked` states. I used static data (Book) for `value`.

```
 <label>
<input type="checkbox" value="Books" @change="handleCategory($event)" /> Books
```

Now, let's implement `handleCategory` method, but before that, as we know that `Checkbox` and `ListCards` are independents which means we need to define a `bus` to create `event` communication between them and this is your issue so we define the `bus` inside the `main.js`

```
Vue.prototype.$bus = new Vue({});
```

Now we define  `handleCategory` like this :

```
methods: {
    handleCategory(e) {
      this.$bus.$emit("checkCategory", e);
    }
  }
```

**Step Three:**

How can our `ListCards` listen to this `event` ?

By call `$bus.$on(..)` when the component is `created` ( Hope you know what Vue lifecycle methods mean )

```
created() {
    this.$bus.$on("checkCategory", e => this.checkCategory(e));
  },
```

When the user click the check box the component runs  `handleCategory` then runs `checkCategory` inside `ListCard`.

Inside my ListCard, I have `categories` and `originalCategories` as data

```
 data() {
    return {
      categories: this.$myArray,
      originalCategories: this.$myArray
    };
  },
```

and a template :

```
<ul v-for="(category,index) in categories" :key="index">
      <CategoryItem :categoryName="category" />
    </ul>
```

and a `created` method ( lifecycle )

```
 created() {
    // $bus is a global object to communicate between components
    this.$bus.$on("checkCategory", e => this.checkCategory(e));
  },
```

and our filtering methods :

```
 methods: {
    checkCategory(e) {
      let target = e.target;
      let value = e.target.value;

      target.checked
        ? this.filterCatergories(value)
        : (this.categories = this.originalCategories);
    },
    filterCatergories(value) {
      this.categories = this.categories.filter(val => val === value);
    }
  }
```

What's important for you is :

```
this.categories.filter(val => val === value); //will not do nothing
const categories=this.categories.filter(val => val === value); //will update the view.
```

And you can change the code or make it better and simple.

**@Update**

You can also use computed properties but because we have a parameter here which is the category name we need `get` and `set`.

```
  computed: {
    filteredItems: {
      get: function() {
        if (this.selectedCategory.length == 0) return this.items;
        return this.items.filter(value => {
          for (const category of this.selectedCategory) {
            if (value == category) return value;
          }
        });
      },
      set: function(category) {
        this.selectedCategory.push(category);
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    checkCategory(e) {
      let target = e.target;
      let value = e.target.value;

      target.checked
        ? (this.filteredItems = value)
        : this.selectedCategory.pop(value);
    }
  }
```